# Path parameters with arbitrary depth in Gorilla/Mux

Tags: go, url-routing, gorilla

I've been working on making a API that would send a json response by reading contents from a json file

*data.json*

```json
{
    "data_1" : {
        "depth2" : {
            "depth3" : "Value of data 1"
        }
    },
    "data_2" : {
        "depth2" : {
            "depth3" : "Value of data 2"
        }
    },
    "data_3" : {
        "depth2" : {
            "depth3" : "Value of data 3"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to make a dynamic nested routing system where if the client requests for, say `/api/data_1/depth2` I want the response to be like

```json
{
   "depth3" : "Value of data 1"
}
```

Let me make it clear that the request path can be indefinitely deep... like `/api/data_1/depth2` or `/api/data_1/depth2/depth3` or even  `/api/data_1/depth2/depth3/depth4` (depending upon *data.json*) which means I cant make my paths like `/api/{var_1}/{var_2}` since its depth is fixed (ie 2 layers)

I need help in solving this in my code

**server.go**

```golang
package main

import (
   ....
   ....
)

func main() {

  // I'm using Gorilla/mux in my project
  router := mux.NewRouter()

  // Handle requests 
  router.HandleFunc("/api/what_should_I_write_here?", ApiHandler)

  // Starting Server
  log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
}
```

I already have a function `NestedLookUp(data map[string]interface{}, key[]string)` that will return data from a nested `map[string]interface{}` if the key is `["data_1", "depth2" ...]` called inside `ApiHandler`. I only have problem figuring the correct route for my `router`

Comment: if depth is arbitrary, you should pass the selector as a parameter (query parameter, or POST body or *single* path parameter) that the handler will interpret based on your application logic

Comment: @blackgreen isn't there a way to do that in the url path ? or route all requests of a url to a single function? where I can split the url string and get my keys

Comment: if you are trying to get keys in url string, `r *http.Request` inside handler function gives you URL.Query() like so `r.URL.Query()`. I suppose there you can access the query by key names? For example, I think you can put key name like depthPath and give keys 1-2-3-4-5 representing depth1 -> depth2 -> ... -> depth 5.

Answer (score 2):

Just to elaborate my comment, if there's an indefinite depth, why don't you get your depth path like so?

```
func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    sub := r.HandleFunc("/api", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        q := r.URL.Query()
        depthPath := q.Get("depthPath")
        depthPathArr := strings.Split(depthPath, "-")

        // depthPath []string{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
        // write function that follow the depthPath
    })
    srv := &http.Server{
        Handler: r,
        Addr: "localhost:7890",
        WriteTimeout: 15 * time.Second,
        ReadTimeout: 15 * time.Second,
    }
    log.Fatal(srv.ListenAndServe())
}
```